# undefined symbol when running gtkmm code in another computer

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I'm making a program in c++ that uses gtkmm, and when I sent it to a friend to test, to make sure it would run in another computer, he got the following error:

`./a.out: symbol lookup error: ./a.out: undefined symbol: _ZN4Glib7ustringC1EONSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE`

I sent him the program already compiled, since I have to turn in just the executable.

Do you need to have the Gtk library installed in order to run code written in it? cause my friend doesn't, and neither will the people running the program when I turn it in. If this is the case, how can I deal with this?

I am running Arch linux with cinnamon, and he is running Ubuntu with unity; could that difference be what's causing the problem?

I can post the code if asked to, but would rather not since it's spread across multiple files and is written in spanish.

Answer (score 0):

Complied the program on his machine and it worked, the problem must have been because of the modifications the arch kernel has.